# Generating Model from Datasource using Report Manager

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas

I am trying to generate Model based  on MS SQL Server Analysis Services. To do so I am following these steps:

1. Select a Datasource (that points to Analysis services database) from
   Report Manager
2. Click on "Generate Model"
3. Enter Name, Description and select location for the Model
4. Click on "OK"

Instead of Model I am getting below error message:

***The ID property for the Role "xxxxxxxx" has a local name that exceeds the maximum length of 250 characters. (IDLocalNameLengthExceeded) Get Online Help***

Where "xxxxxxxx" is my cube name.

I am sure that this SSAS database is working fine without any issue and also I have checked name/id of the cube that doesn't have more than 250 characters but I am not able to generate Model, please any one can suggest a solution for this? I am using SQL Server 2008R2(RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel x86)

Comment: Maybe http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a520ba1-a5f2-4bd6-91f0-ebd714dc9744/cant-generate-report-model?forum=sqlreportingservices can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of cubes, dimensions ect should be short if we want to create a Report Model from SSAS database. The most important thing to note here is - the length of name does not mean the length of name of individual cubes, dimensions only. It also include the qualified path e.g. "yourcube/yourdimension", so when we talk about the length it is length of full qualified name.